# (Java) Erro ao conectar com o SQL Server Local

Tags: java, sql

Estou tentando fazer meu projeto conectar com SQL Server Local, porém está apresentando o seguinte erro:

```
run:
Algo deu errado! 
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: C:\Program Files\sqljdbc_6.0\ptb\jre8\sqljdbc42.jar
```

O arquivo `sqljdbc42` está no destino: `C:\Program Files\sqljdbc_6.0\ptb\jre8\sqljdbc42.jar`

IP do SQL: 192.168.0.12 - Porta padrão: 1433

> Segue o meu código para teste:

```
package testesql;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.sql.DriverManager; 


//import com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver;

/**
 *
 * @author Ronison Matos
 */
public class TesteSQL {

static final String JDBC_DRIVER = "C:\\Program Files\\sqljdbc_6.0\\ptb\\jre8\\sqljdbc42.jar";
static final String DB_URL = "jdbc:sqlserver://192.168.0.12:1433;DatabaseName=Estoque";

// Database credentials
static final String USER = "sa";
static final String PASS = "123456";

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here



    Connection conn = null;
    Statement stmt = null;
    try {
        // Register JDBC driver
        Class.forName(JDBC_DRIVER);

        // Open a connection
        System.out.println("Connecting to database...");
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PASS);

        stmt = conn.createStatement();
        String sql = "SELECT cod_prod FROM Produto";

        ResultSet result = stmt.executeQuery(sql);

        // Show result
        while (result.next()) {
            // Retrieve by column name
            int cod_prod = result.getInt("cod_prod");
            //int age = result.getInt("salary");
            //String first = result.getString("first");
            //String last = result.getString("last");

            // Display values
            System.out.print("ID: " + cod_prod);
            //System.out.print("\t Pay: " + age);
            //System.out.print("\tFirst: " + first);
            //System.out.println("\tLast: " + last);

        }
        // Clean-up
        result.close();
        stmt.close();
        conn.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Algo deu errado! \n" + e);
    }

}
```

}

Comment: tentou executar o programa com `java -classpath` apontando para a pasta onde está o `sqljdbc42.jar`?

Comment: No `Class.forName` vc passa o nome da classe do driver, e não o caminho do jar - algo como `Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver")` (**confirme na documentação o nome correto**). O jar deve estar no classpath, seja via linha de comando, conforme comentário acima, seja via configuração da sua IDE/gerenciador de dependências, mas não precisa referenciar o arquivo diretamente no código

Comment: Fiz conforme mencionado pelo @hkotsubo. Passei por `Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver")`  o mesmo erro persiste. Também realizei uma atualização/baixei o `sqljdbc_6.2.2.1_enu.exe`, também sem avanço.

Comment: @RicardoPontual, por gentileza pode me explica com mais detalhes como devo fazer esse procedimento? Para mim, tudo sobre isso é novidade rs. Desde já agradeço a todos pela ajuda.

Comment: >Resolvido!< Estava faltando referenciar o arquivo `sqljdbc42.jar` dentro do projeto, feito isso resolveu esse erro. Mas surgiu outro erro que provavelmente terei que fazer outra pergunta... Erro: `java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:microsoft:sqlserver://192.168.0.12:1433;databaseName=Estoque`